# Why doesn't creating a case from API work?

Tags: api, civicase

I think this is a bug.

From the API Explorer, I can successfully run this to create a new case, and it is auto-populated with the default Sequence:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Case', 'create', array(
  'sequential' => 1,   
  'contact_id' => 4243,
  'case_type_id' => "member_application",
  'creator_id' => 1033,
  'subject' => "Application",
  'medium_id' => 6,
));
```

But running that same code as a hook fails with the error:

```
CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "source_contact_id is not a valid integer"
```

It actually does create the case and the initial Open Case activity, but seems to fail while trying to create the first activity in my Sequence, which is not created.

I can fix it by editing api/v3/utils.php and adding this at line 1956:

```
if ($fieldValue =='user_contact_id')
  $fieldValue = 1033;
```

I think what's happening is that somewhere along the line, it sets the value of source_contact_id to 'user_contact_id'.  The _civicrm_api3_validate_integer function is supposed to replace this with the currently logged in user.  This works correctly when running from the API Explorer, but not when running from a hook.

The proper solution would be to pass the API "creator_id" through to "source_contact_id" for the extra activities, but I don't know how to fix that.  My hack to hard code the contact works for me for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for sharing this, I agree that it looks like a bug. Instructions on filing a bug report here: https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is normal behavior for the api, although the error message is a bit obtuse. By default it will not create cases or activities (or anything else for that matter) if the logged-in user does not have permission to do so.

Add `'check_permissions' => 0` to your api params if you wish it to proceed without permission checks.

Comment: I tried adding 'check_permissions' => 0 to no effect.  (Isn't it 0 by default anyway?  Or is that for certain other sets of the API?)